# Node.js, Express, Express.Router CRUD template to avoid duplication in routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

For example:

You have a /foo route that has basic CRUD operations:

```
//Create
router.post("/foo", (req, res, next)) => { //foo specific code});
//Read
router.get("/foo", (req, res, next)) => { //foo specific code});
//Update
router.put("/foo", (req, res, next)) => { //foo specific code});
//Delete
router.delete("/foo", (req, res, next)) => { //foo specific code});
```

So say then I need a /bar route... This route will require all the same methods (and perhaps some more). Is there some way that I could create some base route that all of my routes can inherit?

Comment: What exactly do you want to avoid? I mean, all this actions require different responses. What exactly do you want to "share"?

Comment: I want to avoid lots of duplication basically. You're right in saying there will be different responses since I will want to return different models but they will all be 'records' in my db after all so why can't they be treated the same and the system be smart enough to know the type of model to return at runtime. This is similar to something a lot of people do when using the repository pattern in .net where they would establish a base repository that would only include CRUDs that all repositories would inherit. More specific db actions are then written in the child repository e